# I am unable to implement the forEach loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

This is the image of the array named database I am using
[image]

I don't know how to use the forEach loop properly, can someone say why this does not work?
This is what I tried.
[image]

Comment: There's no need to use `forEach` in this case.

Comment: Do not use picture of code. Put your code directly within the question with a code snippet. Check the documentation for the ForEach loop.

Comment: If we just want to implement using forEach, won't that be possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @Teemu okay! I will use for loop then.

Comment: [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would be the correct choise. I hope this is for practising only, you're really not bringing the usernames and passwords from your database to the client?

Comment: You should know that even if your loop worked, it always compares a variable to itself... so it will always be true, so it will never go to the `alert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var database = [{
  username: 'gaurav',
  password: 'password'
}, {
  username: 'gaurav1',
  password: 'password1'
}, {
  username: 'gaurav2',
  password: 'password2'
}];

database.forEach(credential => {// credential is the object = {username, password}
  if (credential.username === credential.username && credential.password === credential.password) {
    console.log('matched');
  }
})
```

forEach will expect function having array of objects as "database" is having collection of objects. So we cannot have 2 separate parameters as you are passing "function (username, password)". It should be function(obj).

Comment: This answers the OP's question, but this is not very handy, if you've an array of million objects to search.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your forEach loop doesn't work is that you are passing it a function that looks like this:

```js
function f(user, password) {
  password == 'examplepassword';
  user == 'someuser';
}
```

Your function is taking the wrong parameters. `forEach` goes over an array, and passes each item of the array to the function you are giving it. The function should be instead written like:

```js
function f(item) {
  item.password == 'examplepassword';
  item.user == 'someuser';
}
```

So you would want to rewrite your code to be more like

```js
db = [{username: 'a', password: 'abc'}, {username: 'b', password: 'bca'}]

db.forEach(function(user) {
  console.log("user " + user.username + " has password " + user.password);
})
/* Output:
user a has password abc
user b has password bca
*/
```

Extra credit:

You can find more details in [the documentation for forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). The function you pass forEach can also have two other arguments, the nº of the item it is currently passed, and the original array.

```
let a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
function f(item, position, array) {
  console.log("The letter " + item + " is in position " + position)
  console.log("array[position] == " + array[position])
}

a.forEach(f);

/* Output:
The letter a is in position 0
array[position] == a
The letter b is in position 1
array[position] == b
The letter c is in position 2
array[position] == c
*/
```

Comment: I just missed that we can't exit a forEach loop if some element is present.

Comment: @GauravDas You're welcome! Remember to accept/vote the answer if you like it!

Comment: @GauravDas "_we can't exit a forEach_" Exactly, that's why I said you should use `some` instead.